# how to execute commands within a docker image inside bamboo build plan agent?

Tags: docker, bamboo

I know how to access a docker image within the bamboo agent (`docker run -t -i the-image-name /bin/bash`), but I can't find way to execute a command after I get in so I can see what's inside the docker image at the time after certain tasks are executed.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you get a shell or not?

Comment: @tadman yes in local, but same command in bamboo agent, it does not show anything in the log.

Comment: You're going to have to expand on this a lot more as to what you're seeing and doing, but also this is better suited to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) as it's not programming per-se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy ways you can achieve this:

1. If you just want to see the console to see if certain commands were run check out the [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command: `docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER`.  This will output into Bamboo what is going on inside the container.
2. If you want to log into the container and execute commands then you will need to use the [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command: `docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARGS]`